# android, php, parsing JSON in php file sent from android

Tags: php, http-post, json

i have this JSON

```
{
   "count":"3",
   "num":"1",
   "array":[
      {
         "id":"a_a",
         "amount":56,
         "duration":"0:12",
         "time":1234566,
         "type":0
      },
      {
         "id":"a_a",
         "amount":56,
         "duration":"0:12",
         "time":1234566,
         "type":1
      }
   ]
}
```

created it in android and send it by `**HttpPost**`

, i've tried a lot of ways to get the data in the php, my php file is this:

```
<?php
    $response = array();
//$json_data = json_encode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']))

    $josn = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $json_data = json_decode($josn,true);

    $count = $json_data->{'count'};
    $num = $json_data["num"];

     $response["data"]=$count;
     $response["data2"]=$num;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

but `$count` and `$num` always returns null, any help please, and thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `$josn` has any value in? Can you show us output?

Comment: yes it returns `{\\\"count\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"num\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"array\\\":[{\\\"id\\\":\\\"a_a\\\",\\\"amount\\\":56,\\\"duration\\\":\\\"0:12\\\",\\\"time\\\":1234566,\\\"type\\\":0},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"a_a\\\",\\\"amount\\\":56,\\\"duration\\\":\\\"0:12\\\",\\\"time\\\":1234566,\\\"type\\\":1},{\\\"id\\\":\\\"a_a\\\",\\\"amount\\\":56,\\\"duration\\\":\\\"0:12\\\",\\\"time\\\":1234566,\\\"type\\\":2}]}`

Comment: And what does `$json_data` output then?

Comment: i know its a bit messy sorry for that, and when i try  `stripslashes($_REQUEST['jsonarray'])`
i had `{\"count\":\"2\",\"num\":\"1\",\"array\":[{\"id\":\"a_a\",\"amount\":56,\"duration\":\"0:12\",\"time\":1234566,\"type\":0},{\"id\":\"a_a\",\"amount\":56,\"duration\":\"0:12\",\"time\":1234566,\"type\":1},{\"id\":\"a_a\",\"amount\":56,\"duration\":\"0:12\",\"time\":1234566,\"type\":2}]}`

Comment: Run stripslashes twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json_data = json_decode($josn,true);
```

this returns an array, not an object (which you are using later in the code). Use this to convert the json string to an object:

```
$json_data = json_decode($josn);
```

---

Or you could just use arrays, in which case your code should look like:

```
<?php
$response = array();
//$json_data = json_encode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']))

$josn = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json_data = json_decode($josn, true); // using true to get array

$count = $json_data["count"]; // accessing array values as normal
$num = $json_data["num"]; // accessing array values as normal

$response["data"] = $count; // instead of setting $count first you could just add
$response["data2"] = $num; // the json_data array values directly to the response array

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: thanks a lot @JimL , my problem is that am not that familiar with php, and using arrays or object in php , but know i knew how to get an array or an single object from the json , thank you so much